# Flutter Ios prevent screenshot app review rejection

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store

I've received this rejection from AppStore:

Guideline 4.0 - Design

We noticed that your app shows a custom screenshot-initiated interface when the user takes a screenshot, but the interface duplicates the iOS system-provided screenshot interface and functionality.

Duplicating system-provided interfaces does not provide the simple, innovative, and easy to use experience App Store users expect.

I've add this in app delegate

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {

    self.window.makeSecure()       //This line to activate the extension

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}


// Extension
extension UIWindow {
func makeSecure() {
    let field = UITextField()
    field.isSecureTextEntry = true
    self.addSubview(field)
    field.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    field.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    self.layer.superlayer?.addSublayer(field.layer)
    field.layer.sublayers?.first?.addSublayer(self.layer)
  }
}
```

What is the wrong ? and how to solve this issue
Note : I've already used this method on initial upload and they accepted it .. but now in update they reject it.

Comment: Most likely they are getting confused because when they take a screenshot, they don't see the screen they expect. You could try explaining that your app prevents screenshots and they will get a blank view when taking a screenshot or remove screenshot prevention because it is pointless

Comment: I explained the behavior two times ... but they still keep reject it for same reason ... i can't remove it because i want my content still secured inside the app.

Comment: But your content isn't protected by this. Cameras are a thing.

Comment: yes but at least you did't want to see video or image captured by camera specially for something like videos with length of hour or more

Comment: But you aren't talking about hour long video. You are talking about a screen shot.  There is a [different approach](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1970/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017687) available to prevent screen recording

Comment: the method above make it black screen when you take screenshot or video recording

Comment: Not screenshot. You can use that approach to detect that the screen is "captured", by iOS screen recording or QuickTime via a lightning cable, and show alternate content

Comment: and how to do that?

Comment: Follow the link in my comment above. You can check the `isCaptured` property of `UIScreen` and display alternate content if it is `true`. This will be more complex in Flutter; you will need some native code that can stream the state of that property to your Dart code and then you can update your view there. This won't help you with screen shots though, only screen recording.

Comment: @NehilKoshiya not yet ☹️